# read and write array at the same time python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to recalculate column "a" of a given dataframe = df. But my way of doing it does not fill in the new, calculated values over the old ones.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from numpy.random import randn

 df = pd.DataFrame(randn(100))
 df["a"] = np.nan
 df["b"] = randn()
 df.a[0] = 0.5

 df.a= df.a.shift(1) * df.b
```

Do you have any ideas how I can fill to solve that?

I want to calculate "a" depending on its previous value an "b":

```
      a       b      
     0.5      2            #set as starting value with df.a[0] = 0.5  since there is no value for a prior to that, there's no calculation performed.
     1.5      3            # a = previous value of a *b (0.5*3) =1.5
     15       10           # a = previous value of a *b (1.5*10) =15
     45       3            # a = previous value of a *b (15*3) =45
```

The problem is that the calcation does not perform / results of calcutation do not overwrite previously set values.

Comment: do you mean `df["b"] = np.random.randn()`?

Comment: that fills df.b with random values

Comment: what do you want? currently your are filling b with a function

Comment: you are, right. I already edited it. But df.a gets still not calculated new...

Comment: Not sure about your math.  Doesn't 0.5*2 = 1.0 and 15*3=45? I don't believe your question is clear enough about the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None] * 4, 'b': [2, 3, 10, 3]})
df.a.iloc[0] = 0.5
df.a.iloc[1:] = (df.b.shift(-1).cumprod() * df.a.iat[0])[:-1].values

>>> df
     a   b
0  0.5   2
1  1.5   3
2   15  10
3   45   3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a `for` loop like this:

```
for i in df.index[1:]:
   df.a.ix[i] = df.b.ix[i]*df.a.ix[i-1]
```

If anyone knows a vectorized way I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: Yes, exactly, thats the problem. I want recalculate df.a depending on the value I set in df.a[0], so insted of NaN there should be the newly calculated vales.

Comment: I don't understand... can you edit your question to include your desired output?

Comment: Cool I understand your question now, let me have another go.

Comment: It brings me this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'long' and 'NoneType' - maybe it's just my dataframe?